Optimizing Proxmox VM allocation for ERP and Windows Server on HP ProLiant DL380 G10
I'm setting up an HP ProLiant DL380 G10 (16-core Xeon, 32GB RAM) with Proxmox VE for our small business (15 users). I plan to run two VMs:
CentOS ERP: 4 cores, 16GB RAM
Windows Server (DC, file sharing): 4 cores, 8GB RAM
My specific concerns are:
Is this VM resource allocation optimal for my use case?
With 32GB total RAM, am I allocating too much to the VMs and not leaving enough for the hypervisor?
How can I best configure storage for these VMs using the available SSDs and SAS drives?
Any advice on optimizing this setup for better performance would be appreciated.
This version:
Focuses on specific concerns about resource allocation
Asks clear questions about RAM distribution and storage configuration
Provides enough context for users to understand your setup
Invites specific advice on optimization
This should meet SuperUser's requirements for a more focused, problem-specific question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
